# Getting all sorts of errors on basic code. No clue why

Tags: c++

i have this super basic vector code. For some reason i'm receiving tons of errors???

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

    int amount = 0;
    int nums = 0;
    std::vector <int> vec[amount];

    std::cin >> amount;

    while (std::cin >> nums);
        vec.push_back(nums);

    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end);

    return 0;
}
```

Where have i gone wrong here? I'm receiving all of these errors. Not a single clue what the issue is...

```
expression must have a constant value -- the value of variable "amount" (declared at line 12) cannot be used as a constant

request for member 'push_back' in 'vec', which is of non-class type 'std::vector<int> [amount]'

'sort' was not declared in this scope

identifier "sort" is undefined

request for member 'begin' in 'vec', which is of non-class type 'std::vector<int> [amount]'

request for member 'end' in 'vec', which is of non-class type 'std::vector<int> [amount]'
```

Comment: I see no `#includes`. `std::vector <int> vec[amount];` is an array of `vector`s, on systems that allow variable length arrays (and arrays of length 0). Arrays have no `push_pack` method. No methods at all, to be honest.

Comment: There are a few things going on here that are sufficiently incorrect that it's hard to tell your intent. Can you add a synopsis of what you're trying to achieve? (I'd also note that a vector is already a data structure that can store a variable number of items, there's no need to make an array *of vectors*. Further, your while loop does nothing in its body because of the semicolon; it may be necessary to break this down into sub-problems and revisit the fundamentals in each one.

Comment: Apologies, forgot to paste in the headers to my question, but they are there.

Comment: I'm just trying to let the user determine the size of the array and then push numbers in to it and then order them from smallest to largest.

Comment: I think you're looking for `std::vector <int> vec(amount);` (English: Give me a `vector` with `amount` values--zeros in this case--already in it), but placed after the user has provided a value for `amount`. But that's kinda silly since it's stuffing the `vector` with 0s, then adding more values, and sorting the zeros along with the user's inputs.

Comment: And, maybe `vec.end()` instead of `vec.end`...